# How do I deploy multiple Java projects to the same Azure cloud service and storage account?

Tags: java, eclipse, azure

I am just beginning to learn Azure, so I expect this will seem an elementary question.  Using Eclipse (and the Windows Azure Plugin with Java) I began by writing a basic JSP (html) file that simply displays some text in the browser.

Deployment of the first project went fine. It ran as intended in the storage and compute emulators, deployed fine into the new cloud service and storage account I added to Azure, works fine in staging and then production.  I deployed the JDK and application server in the package.

I created a second project in Eclipse, same as the first, except that the project and application names are different. This package also includes the JDK and application server. Works fine in the emulator, but when I try to deploy to the existing Azure cloud service and storage account, it fails.

…

Uploading deployment package - 100% Completed

02/22/2013 12:29:45 - Creating deployment

02/22/2013 12:29:47 - Failed : HTTP error code : 409 Conflict

Is it not possible to deploy multiple projects to the same cloud service and storage account?

The first application is still running in the cloud.

thanks

ANSWER SUMMARY
Martin's answer resolved this issue for me.  Although Eclipse did not display a message when I tried to publish to an existing cloud service, I was able to unpublish the existing cloud service and then publish to staging and then production as expected.

Comment: I see also now that this account is limited to one storage and one hosted service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're publishing a newer version of the same service, then just click the Unpublish button on the toolbar (next to the Publish one) to remove your previous deployment first.

If you're intentionally publishing a whole different application that is supposed exist in addition to the one you already published, then you need to create a new service for it in the publish dialog, rather than selecting the same service again (which happens by default).

And if you're just adding another WAR to the same container installation (Tomcat and or what not), then do that in the Eclipse Azure project, and then republish - that is equivalent to publishing the same deployment in the same service (so you need to unpublish the previous one).

Comment: I unpublished and removed all the services had. I added a new service. So I have now have one service, one storage acct. However when try to publish in Eclipse, fails Failed : HTTP error code : InternalError
The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request.

Comment: That might be just a temporary fluke in Azure - we see those internal errors every now and then still.  Just wait it out and try again later...

Answer (score 2):

I do not think so, when you publish the second project to the same cloud service, Eclipse will ask you to unpublish your first one.

Comment: Thanks Albert - Eclipse did not ask me to unpublish the first service. When I tried create a second service (without removing the first) it failed - 02/22/2013 02:31:34 - Failed : HTTP error code : InternalError
The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request.